AG Chart Time Axis Luxon DateTime vs js Date
Does the AG Chart API provide a callback for a data series to provide for converting the data format?
We use Luxon DateTime objects in our application, but it appears AG Chart only supports JS Date or strings or numbers that equate to a date/time.
I am hoping I won't have to convert our existing series into another set with JSDates, but seems like that might be the only option.
